# cannot emit event within function

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have problem with sending emit:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log("connected");
  socket.emit("connected", 1);

  socket.on("news", function (data) {
    console.log(data.event_type + " <-- get data");                        
    socket.emit("socket", data);
  });             

  socket.on('my other event', 1);
  socket.on("fb", function (data) {
    socket.emit("wy", "no");
  });   
});
```

I'm running this script on server and getting event `"news"` from app on my raspberry. I can't emit event `"socket"` to website,  even after i get in console `"<-- get data"` with data value. I tried to make another emit (`"my other event"`) and sent it to website and it was executed without a problem.

Here is code on website:

```
var socket = io.connect();
socket.on("socket", function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});

socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
  console.log( data);
  socket.emit("fb",  { my: 'data' });
});
socket.on("wy", function (data) {
  console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue.  When I try your code in my own server and web page, I get the event "socket" just fine.

Comment: Did you just miss typing what goes after `socket.on('my other event')` or is that an actual error in your code? (You don't have the function defined, and are missing the semicolon after it...). Don't know if that would cause your problem or not. But the other emits look right to me

Comment: I fixed some minor bugs but it still doesn't work. I would like to get something like this:

emit event from rasp -> listen on server and emit another event -> listen event on website.